# Console error onClick where ID does not exist

Tags: javascript

I have a click function which sits inside of my main.js.

When I am on the correct page where this ID is located, there are no errors in console and everything works fine. But when I navigate to another page where the main.js is still being loaded and the ID does not exist, my console gives me this error.

```
main.js?7a2b:51 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property 'onclick' of null
```

Any suggestions would be great

thanks

Comment: We can't help you unless you give us code to look at. Post a [mcve] please

Comment: So seems like someone needs to check if the element exists before attaching the events. Or do not load JavaScript on a page that should not run....

Comment: It's in a bundle so hard not to run on a certain page

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to check if the element that you want to select actually exists before you try to add an eventhandler to it. You can check if an element with a certain id exists like so:

```js
var element = document.getElementById('<MY_ID>');
if(element){
    //Add your eventhandling inside this block
    element.addEventListener('click', function {/* ... */})
}
```